# Событие на обновление строк в DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть `DataGrid`, у которого `ItemsSource={Binding Items}`

Items при изменении отсылает PropertyChanged.

Какое событие возникает при этом? То есть когда происходит `Items = newItems` и строки в таблице обновляются, какое событие происходит в самом конце?

Answer (score 1):

Помогло событие `LoadingRow`. Срабатывает при отрисовке каждой строки таблицы, которая видна на экране. То есть, когда срабатывает с индексом строки 0 коллекция уже получена. Как то так )

```
void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.GetIndex() == 0)
        // мои действия
}
```

**UPD:**

Поправочка. Если скролл будет ниже первого элемента, то строка с индексом 0 не сработает, поэтому подписываемся на изменение свойства с коллекцией (не CollectionChanged, а именно PropertyChanged) и ставим некий флаг в true, а в событии DataGrid_LoadingRow уже проверяем этот флаг и при первом срабатывании переводим его снова в false

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, события довольно неплохо можно посмотреть на [МСДН](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Во вторых - вероятно вам нужно `SourceUpdated`.

Возможно, что подойдет и `LayoutUpdated`.

Comment: SourceUpdated не срабатывает, LayoutUpdated работает как-то хаотично. Зато, оказалось, что мне подошел `LoadingRow`. Срабатывает при загрузке каждой строки таблицы, которая видна на экране. То есть, когда срабатывает с индексом строки 0 коллекция уже получена. Как то так )